# Reading 3 strings from a text file

Tags: c

I am having trouble reading 3 strings from one line, moving to the next one, and putting them in my struct correctly.

My text file looks like this:

```
- John Johnson Math
- Eric Smith Biology
- etc
```

I need to arrange students by class they have chosen. How should i read first string as name then blank, second as last name, and third by class and do that for every line, then store correctly in my struct? Here is what I have right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 30

typedef struct students {
    char nameFirst[MAX];
    char NameLast[MAX];
    char choClass[MAX];
    struct students *next;
} Students;

int main() {
    FILE *in;
    Students *first = NULL, *New = NULL, *last = NULL, *old = NULL, *current = NULL;
    in = fopen("studenti.txt", "r");
    if (in == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file!\n");
        return 1;
    }
while (i = fgetc(in) != (int)(EOF))
{
    New = calloc(1, sizeof(Students));
    if (first == NULL)
        first = New;
    else
        last->next = New;

    j = 0;
    while (i != (int)(' '))
    {
        New->nameFirst[j++] = (char)i;
        i = fgetc(in);
    }
    New->nameFirst[j] = '\0';
}
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't look like much of a genuine effort. Have you tried to read the file at all? In any way? There are alot of examples out there and surely you can progress further than just opening the file. Or at least make some attempt to.

Comment: I was trying `while(fgets(name, MAX, in) != (int)(EOF))` do some stuff with pointers, but i got write access violation from compiler, i guess i did read it wrong...

Comment: You a better served creating an array of Students and dropping the `next` pointer. A linked list would unnecessarily complicate your project.

Comment: `fgets` seems like a reasonable start. So do show that code and explain what problems you are having with it.

Comment: ok , here is my attempt reading it char by char for the first name, obviously i didnt format it correctly, oops :(

Comment: i have putted it in a code above, my try reading it char by char, until blank right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, why are you approaching this problem with a *linked-list*? You can use a linked list, but the overhead and code complexity is more than required. A straight forward solution is a simply dynamic array of type `students`. The benefits of an array or significant. Direct access to all student, simple sorting with a single call to `qsort`, simple additions, etc..

Don't get me wrong, if you assignment is to use a *linked-list*, by all means do, but you should really look at an dynamic array of type `student`, where you can `realloc` as needed to add as many students as you may like.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 30, MAXS = 60, MAXLN = 128 };

typedef struct students {
    char first[MAXC];
    char last[MAXC];
    char class[MAXC];
} students;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    students *array = NULL;
    size_t i, idx = 0, maxs = MAXS;
    char buf[MAXLN] = "";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate maxs students in array */
    if (!(array = malloc (maxs * sizeof *array))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXLN, fp)) {    /* read each line into buf */
        /* separate in to struct members */
        if (sscanf (buf, "- %s %s %s", array[idx].first,
                    array[idx].last, array[idx].class) != 3)
            continue;

        if (++idx == maxs) {    /* check against current allocations */
            void *tmp = realloc (array, (maxs + MAXS) * sizeof *array);
            if (!tmp) {         /* valdate realloc array succeeded */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc memory exhausted.\n");
                break;          /* or break and use existing data   */
            }
            array = tmp;        /* assign reallocated block to array */
            maxs += MAXS;       /* update current allocations size   */
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    printf ("\nstudents:\n\n");     /* output formatted data   */
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        char tmp[2 * MAXC + 2] = "";
        strcpy (tmp, array[i].last);
        strcat (tmp, ", ");
        strcat (tmp, array[i].first);
        printf (" %-60s %s\n", tmp, array[i].class);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    free (array);   /* free all allocated memory */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** if your data file really doesn't begin each line with `'- '`, then just remove that from the `sscanf` *format-string*)

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/studentclass.txt
- John Johnson Math
- Eric Smith Biology
- etc.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/structstudents <dat/studentclass.txt

students:

 Johnson, John                                                Math
 Smith, Eric                                                  Biology
```

**Memory Error/Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 responsibilites regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) always preserves a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory so, (2) it can be freed when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an unintitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. e.g.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/structstudents <dat/studentclass.txt
==14062== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14062== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14062== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14062== Command: ./bin/structstudents
==14062==

students:

 Johnson, John                                                Math
 Smith, Eric                                                  Biology

==14062==
==14062== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14062==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14062==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 5,400 bytes allocated
==14062==
==14062== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14062==
==14062== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14062== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Always confirm *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and equally important *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*.

Look it over an let me know if the array approach fits your needs and if you have any questions.

**Sorting by `class` member**

In order to sort the array of `struct students` by the `class`, the easiest way is to use the `qsort` function. It is the standard sorting function provided by the C library (include `stdio.h`). You can sort by any member of the `students` struct. You can even sort by class, and by name.

The only problem new programmers have with `qsort` is writing the *compare* function to pass to `qsort` in order to have it sort in the desired order. The *compare* function will receive a pointer to two elements in your array of struct student. The parameters passes are passed as `void *` (`const void *` actually). Just like any `void` pointer, you must cast it to the proper type before you can dereference it. (in this case `students *`) Therefore, you simply need a function that casts the `void` pointers to `students *` and passes the values to `strcmp`. Example:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{ 
    return strcmp (((students *)a)->class, ((students *)b)->class);
}
```

The only thing left is calling `qsort` (after `fclose` in the code):

```
qsort (array, idx, sizeof *array, compare);
```

Your output is then sorted by class.

If you then want to sort further by `last` name after sorting by `class`, instead of returning on the `strcmp` for `class`, test if the result is not equal to zero, and return that result. If the result of the `strcmp` on `class` is zero, then you simply `return strcmp (((students *)a)->last, ((students *)b)->last);`  That simply sorts by `class` first, but if the class is the same, sorts further by `last`. For example:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{ 
    int r;
    if ((r = strcmp (((students *)a)->class, ((students *)b)->class)))
        return r;

    return strcmp (((students *)a)->last, ((students *)b)->last);
}
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/studentclass.txt
- Wade Williams Biology
- John Johnson Math
- Eric Smith Biology
- etc.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/structstudents <dat/studentclass.txt

students:

 Smith, Eric                                                  Biology
 Williams, Wade                                               Biology
 Johnson, John                                                Math
```

Take the time to learn `qsort`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, no i don't have to use struct, i will do it like you said and try to finish it. It was a quality answer and read for me, especially memory part. Once again thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. Everyone needs an example or two to get going. The key to learning C is to slow-down. There is a lot to learn and C the low-level control C provides means it is up to you to account for each block of memory you use. Most other languages go to a great deal of trouble to handle memory management behind the scenes, in C it is up to you. So *slow-down* and take time to understand the memory used by a `char`, then an array of `char`, a `struct`, and array of `struct`, etc. You will do fine.

Comment: I made the list like you said, and it's working great, my question is, how should i sort the list alphabetically by classes only, not their names? What function should i use for that?

Comment: To sort by class, you will use `qsort`. You will need to write a `compare` function that compares the `classes`. That could be done with `int compare (const void *a, const void *b) { return strcmp (((students *)a)->class, ((students *)b)->class); }`. You then just call `qsort (array, idx, sizeof *array, compare);` before you print.

Comment: thank you very much, i used i `qsort`, but without `compare` function, and he just sorted my string, but not the list. I knew i was missing something. Thank you sir!